# Delete row of a cell array which is not equal to a certain value

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have cell array like `A = {1;2;3;4;5}`

I want to remove the row where value in the cell is equal to 4.

I tried
`b = A{A~=3}`; but it does not work with cell array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
A = {1;2;3;4;5}
A([A{:}] == 4) = []

A = 

    [1]
    [2]
    [3]
    [5]
```

Comment: when i try this my 19754 x 1 cell array, it gives "Matrix index is out of range for deletion." do you know why?

Comment: This array may appear in loops. Please post your loop in a new question, as this error is not related to this question. Keep the code as short as possible, but sufficient to reproduce the error.